# Cannot create SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a database and I get the error below[image]

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx

Comment: error message looks pretty explicit...

Comment: The message may be explicit but the answer is not, I am in administrator mode.

Comment: "Administrator mode" being a Windows administrator? That has little bearing on your SQL permissions.

Answer (score 1):

you need permission to create a database. The simplest solution would be to connect with a user that inherits a login that has permission to create databases

Which user are you using to connect to the database?

right click you login and check if you have access to make yourself a dbcreator:

[image]

Comment: when I am logged in as administrator I cannot create give myself the 'dbcreator' permission

Comment: It would help if you tell us why not

Comment: so you didn't log as an administrator. You could have logged as a AD windows admin, which doesn't mean it is a SQL Server sysadmin. Dont you know the sa password?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 262

Click on Start -> Click in Microsoft SQL Server 2005
Now right click on SQL Server Management Studio
Click on Run as administrator
Now the problem is solved. This is the actual process to login to our SQL server 2005 as an administrator with all the administrative rights. But I think in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 express edition we do not need to go through the above process.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SQL Server -> Security -> Logins and create a new login with all permissions and roles.